# How to detect connection quality of a web page

Tags: javascript, connection, latency, qos, speed-test

I have a webapp and I would like to have a js script to constantly monitor the instant quality of the internet connection of the user.

First of all I tought a simple ajax ping or a websocket message exhange and measure the response latency, but I think it is not enought.

Is there any existing solution or idea to create it?

Comment: That could be a tricky one, to really measure the quality you would need the equivalent of speedTest.net type of thing,  the problem is doing this will reduce the quality as it eats all your bandwidth..  ps. Latency could be low, but bandwidth could be high, and latency is really not too much of an issue with webpages unless your making some sort of Game..

Comment: So technically only the latency can be easily measured? However this is not really the ping as ICMP, the HTTP ping is more expensive.

Comment: A Websocket ping would take bytes, so you could setup a winsocket connection if the overhead of a HTTP request for doing a ping is more than you like.